# Recovering an XML file on Oracle Linux 8 with LVM and XFS

Tags: lvm, xfs, oracle-linux

I have a VM with Oracle Linux 8.8 virtualized on VMware, LVM is used and the format is XFS (v6). If I delete a file, for example xml (in users /home), is there any way to recover it?

Its clear that VMs should always have backups, be cautious before deleting files, make snapshots etc.

I deleted an xml file, (it is not critical, nor necessary) but I was left with the doubt of what happens if in some case I must recover a data of this type; there is information online and applications, but for LVM and XFS I have not found one with which I have been able to recover the test file.

I have used some live cd with linux distros for recovery but they have not worked as expected (gparted-live-1.5.0-6-amd64, rescatux-0.74 and systemrescue-10.02-amd64) as well as some apps (testdisk, photorec, Wondershare Recoverit, Scalpel, Extundelete etc).

Regards.